# Remove Right-Click Blockers Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Some sites use scripts that disable right click. Is there a script that will cancel out such scripts?

Comment: I answered this, but it's not really a programming question and doesn't belong here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options, depending on your browser.  In Firefox for example, you can use the [RightToClick](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/righttoclick/) plugin, or [RightToCopy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/righttocopy/plmcimdddlobkphnofejmeidjblideca?hl=en-US) in Chrome.